# RegularExpressionValidator versus Regex.Match in CustomValidator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm surely missing something here, as what I expect to work identically, is working differently.

Suppose the following RegularExpressionValidator syntax

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="rxEmail" ControlToValidate="txEmail"
                    ValidationExpression="<%$ appsettings:rxEmail %>" Text="*" />
```

and the following CustomValidator syntax/code

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvEmail" runat="server" Text="*" onServerValidate="validateContactFormat" />

Sub validateContactFormat(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles cvContactFormat.ServerValidate
        Dim emailRegEx As Regex = New Regex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("rxEmail"))
        args.IsValid = emailRegEx.IsMatch(txEmail.Text)

End Sub
```

The expression held in web.config is

```
[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+
```

which is supposed to be simple, and weed out the most obvious problems, without being too picky.

Anywho, given the input bob.smith@someplace.co.uk - the RegularExpressionValidator fails, but the CustomValidator passes. Other scenarios work as expected.. both pass blah@blah.com, but would fail blah.com. There may be other issues but this is one I noticed.

I guess the code in the CustomValidator isn't the same as what the RegularExpressionValidator would produce 'behind the scenes' - but what exactly is the difference and why do I see what I see?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bob.smith@someplace.co.uk
```

contains a dot before the `@`. That dot isn't matched by `[\w-]+`.

The RegularExpressionValidator checks the *entire*  string against the regex and, correctly, fails.

The CustomValidator (using [`Regex.IsMatch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx)) checks if a *substring* matches (and succeeds with `smith@someplace.co.uk`, again correctly).

To make sure that both behave the same, surround your regex with anchors:

```
"^(?:" + myOldRegex + ")$"
```

Comment: @TablooQuijico: You're welcome, and you're not the first one to be confused by the decision of the .NET team to name that method `IsMatch()` instead of  `Search()` or `Find()` or `IsSubmatch()` or anything that doesn't imply a full match.